# How one can pause and/or stop javafx.concurrent.Task?

Tags: java, javafx

Say, I've got a `javafx.concurrent.Task` nested into `Thread`, ie.:

```
Task task = new Task();
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.start();
```

How can I in this situation pause and/or stop executing `task` nad resume its work?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? For the usual use cases of a task, there would be no point in pausing it? Perhaps there is a better way to do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, except using the deprecated suspend() and resume() methods on the Thread class.

In case you are sure your task doesn't enter synchronized code that would work

Otherwise you would have to have halt points in your task were you check if the Task has been halted and if so call wait() on some object to block the thread. A call to notify on the object would then wake the Thread up and resume. Below is a chunk of pseudo code for that approach.

Note that for this to work as expected you need check the halt variable frequently in the task code.

```
class MyTask{
    volatile boolean halt = false;
    Object o  = new Object();
    public void run(){
        while(notDone) {
            if (halt) halt();

        }
    }

    private halt(){
        synchronized (o){o.wait()}
    }


    public resume(){
        halt = false;
        synchronized (o){o.notify()}
    }
    public suspend(){
        halt=true;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class TestThread {

static class PausableRunnable implements Runnable{
    volatile boolean shouldHalt = false;
    private final Object lock=new Object();
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            if(shouldHalt)halt();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }
    private void halt(){
        synchronized (lock){
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    void pause(){
        shouldHalt = true;
    }

    void resume(){
        synchronized (lock){
            shouldHalt=false;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}

public static void maipn(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PausableRunnable pr = new PausableRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(pr);
    t.start();

    while(true) {
        char c = (char) System.in.read();
        if (c == 'p') {
            System.out.println("Pausing");
            pr.pause();
        }
        if (c == 'r') {
            System.out.println("Resuming");
            pr.resume();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not quite correct.  `volatile` and `synchronized` are generally mutually exclusive. When using one, you shouldn't be using the other.  The `halt` field should always be read and written inside the `synchronized` blocks, to guarantee atomicity and thread safety.  The while-loop should also be inside the `synchronized` block.

Comment: The code is correct, I've added a full implementation.